# Can We build an eclipse ADT project with API Level 29 i am getting error "Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have updated SDK platforms for API Level 29. This is an old project build in eclipse still not migrated to studio,now  i have to build it with API level 29 because having issues with images for Android 11
I want to add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to manifes tto resolve image issue for android 11, But this builds only on API 29.